# Grep Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, grep

I'm trying to show all phone numbers with two nonconsecutive "-" in it.  I've tried these expressions:

```
grep '[-]{2}' phones.txt
grep '-{2}' phones.txt
grep '.*[-].+[-].+$' phones.txt
grep '^\d+[-]\d+[-]\d+$' phones.txt
```

But none are working.  This is my first time using regular expressions and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong

Comment: Are the `-` next to each other? Or can there be other characters in between.

Comment: Are you wanting phone number containing two consecutive '-' characters or just two anywhere in the phone number: ie  12-34-56 should match?

Comment: Your second try looks for a space followed by a hyphen followed by 2 spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like:

```
grep '^.*-.*-.*$' phones.txt
```

This will find the case where the `-` are adjacent and not. The `-` can also be at the beginning or end.

If you're looking to restrict it to numbers like:

```
123-555-3456
```

ie. the `-` are in the "middle" and separated by digits, you can use the more restrictive:

```
grep '[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+-[0-9]\+' phones.txt
```

For my sample `phones.txt`:

```
012-345-678
012-345
012-345-
-012-345
012345
543838--499
--
1-2-3
```

the second pattern matches the following:

```
012-345-678
1-2-3
```

I'm using: grep (GNU grep) 2.4.2

Comment: The first one fails where, the number ends with `-`.

Comment: @iamauser I noted that the number could start or end with a dash for the first pattern. I've fixed the second pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Non consecutive or consecutive can be matched with `(--?)`.   This is a `-` character followed by a `-` which can exist zero or 1 times (optionally followed by).